# Can the "IN" be used only in the "WHERE" clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can the "IN" be used in an other clause than "WHERE"? For instance in an iif:

```
iif((([Date] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Result] in ('PassedWithHonors', 'Passed')), 'Passed', 'Failed)))
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can put it here and there, e.g. CASE, ON, etc

Comment: You could just try it. And what's with all those parentheses, doesn't help the readability.

Comment: "You could just try it"... you have won the palm of the answer of the year! Clap, clap... If I put the question, it means that I already tried to do it, but thank you for your help anyway

Comment: On a different note from my answer, I'd suggest against using an `IIF` like that in your `WHERE` clause; you might make the query non-SARGable. If you'rer simply looking for a `Passed` value and `[date]` not having a non *`NULL`* value then just do: `AND [Date] IS NOT NULL AND Result IN ('PassedWithHonors', 'Passed')`. no need for the `IIF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put an `IN` anywhere you can put a Boolean Expression. One of those places is the `WHERE` clause, but a Boolean expression could almost be anywhere in a query. For example, in the `ON` clause (as @jarlh mentioned), or within the `SELECT`, `GROUP`, `HAVING` clauses within (for example) a `CASE` or `IIF` (but limited to those functions).

It can even go in an `IF` statement as part of your Logical Flow Operations. For example:

```
IF @i IN (1,2) BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable;
END ELSE IF @i in (3,4) BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM YourTable;
END
```

So, like I said at the start, an `IN` can go anywhere you can put a Boolean Expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's what I was looking for! In the tutorials, they always use it in the `where` clause, so I wasn't sure

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
case when [Date] IS NOT NULL AND [Result] in ('PassedWithHonors', 'Passed')
     then 'Passed'
     else 'Failed'
end
```